# Создание вектора по условию

Tags: vector, r, if

Добрый день! Я хочу, чтобы, если число положительное, справа и слева были добавлены 0 и Inf, если отрицательное, то –Inf и 0 таким образом: -Inf   -5    0  или   0   5    Inf.
Пытаясь сделать это с помощью конструкции ifelse, получаю только первое число вектора.

> n <- 5
>
> ifelse(n>0, c(0, n, Inf), c(-Inf, n, 0))

получается:

> [[1]]
>   [1] 0
>
> n <- -5
>
> ifelse(n>0, c(0, n, Inf), c(-Inf, n, 0))

получается:

> [[1]]
>   [1] -Inf

Как быть?

Comment: Тут возникает вопрос, зачем это надо? (ultimate goal)
Выглядит как попытка категоризации непрерывной переменой. В таком случае смотрим в сторону функции `cut()`

Comment: для этого и надо. Может, cut правильно как-то по-другому применять, я делаю так

Comment: > sset <- c(-5,-5,-28,-1,-117,-41,-11,-30,-27,-46,-43,-13,-32,-59,-11,-142,-33,-2,-64,-85,-130)
> tt <- c(0, quantile(sset, probs = c(0.333, 0.666)), Inf)
> cut(-33, tt, right=FALSE, labels=c("низкая", "средняя", "высокая"))
[1] низкая
Levels: низкая средняя высокая

Comment: а если не добавлять границы, то ошибка: > tt <- quantile(sset, probs = c(0.333, 0.666))
> cut(-33, tt, right=FALSE, labels=c("низкая", "средняя", "высокая"))
Error in cut.default(-33, tt, right = FALSE, labels = c("низкая", "средняя",  : 
  длины 'breaks' и 'labels' отличаются

Comment: В приведенном примере проблема с вектором tt (0.00 -44.02 -22.52 Inf). Квантильные значения меньше нуля

Comment: так правильнее? поторопилась > tt <- c(-Inf, quantile(sset, probs = c(0.333, 0.666)), 0)
> tt
        33.3%  66.6%        
  -Inf -44.02 -22.52   0.00  Для этого мне и нужно это условие

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ на исходный вопрос.

> ifelse returns a value with the same shape as test which is filled with elements selected from either yes or no depending on whether the element of test is TRUE or FALSE.

Поэтому достаточно сделать так:

```
ifelse(n>0, list(c(0, n, Inf)), list(c(-Inf, n, 0)))
[[1]]
[1]   0   5 Inf
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Нашла этот вопрос на англоязычном сайте https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335830/why-cant-rs-ifelse-statements-return-vectors , (что всё дело в форме теста), но ваш пример помог в моём конкретном случае